# Using lambda on a method with out parameter as a boolean

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to pass a method that returns a string with an out parameter as a boolean. based on if the method that returns the string, returns the same string.

Barebone sample code that doesn't work because the lambda is invalid:

```
class Class1 {
    void Foo () {
        s = "some value";
        if (() => { (Class2.Foo(s, out s)); })
            return; // Do stuff here
    }
}

public static class Class2 {
    string Foo(string s, out string _s) {
        bool ok = true; // HACK
        _s = "";
        return ok ? _s : s;
    }
}
```

How, if possible, can I make this work properly by only changing/replacing the lambda expression?

Edit: Seems like I've been asking this a bit backwards and silly. Here is more generalized version on what I'm trying to accomplish:

I want to send a method an object of any type, and get either the same object back, or a new one if the function succeeded. I then want to use the method itself as a boolean, so code within the if statement only runs if I get a new object back.

I realize that this is an odd way to do this, but there is method behind this nonsense (at least in my head).

Comment: problem number one, Class2.Foo is not `static` yet you are using it like it is. Problem 2, `s` is not declared anywhere ( in Class1.Foo)

Comment: I didn't include them in my sample code initially, sorry about that. I've updated the sample code now.

Comment: You still have the first problem; it won't compile without it. Also, passing s twice is silly, just do `ref string s` and call it good. There is a third problem as well, `Class2.Foo` does not return a bool, and so its return value can't be used in an `if` statement. The whole code is really messed up and nonsensical really

Comment: It is not exactly clear why you are using a lambada at all here.

Comment: Along with other things you may plan to use `Predicate` here in case you are keen to use Lambda in the if loop.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj `Predicate` would be a bit of an awkward fit here, since `Foo` returns `string`, not `bool`.

Comment: @Abion47, why OP needs boolean via a Lambda method call and predicate is one of the way to achieve it, as its a standard to use 
`Predicate<string>` instead of `Func<string,bool>`

Comment: Thanks for all insight so far. I realize that I have worded myself in my question quite... silly... so here is a more generalized version of what im trying to achieve:

i basically want to send a method an object of any type, and get either the same object back, or a new one if the function succeeded, and i want to the method itself as a boolean, so every code in the if statement only runs if i get a new object back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare values against a lambda expression directly. What you can do is wrap the lambda in a `Func` and check the result:

```
if (new Func<string>(() => Class2.Foo(s, out s)).Invoke() == "some value")
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

It isn't clear from your code exactly *why* you are using a lambda at all, though. If possible, you should instead just call the method:

```
if (Class2.Foo(s, out s) == "some value")
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

---

Per the clarification in the comments, I think it would be better to do one of two things. Either A] have only one `ref` parameter and do the assignment in the method (assisted for cleanliness with generics):

```
class Class1 
{
    void Foo () 
    {
        s = "some value";
        sa = "some other value";

        if (Class2.Foo(ref s, sa))
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
}


public static class Class2 
{
    public static bool Foo<T>(ref T o, T alt) {
        bool ok = // Do some function

        if (ok)
            o = alt;

        return ok;
    }
}
```

or B] just get the correct object back from the method:

```
class Class1 
{
    void Foo () 
    {
        sa = "some value";
        sb = "some other value";
        r = Class2.Foo(sa, sb);

        if (r != sa)
        {
            // Do stuff here
        }
    }
}

public static class Class2 
{
    public static T Foo<T>(T a, T b) 
    {
        bool ok = // Do some function

        if (ok)
            return a;

        return b;
    }
}
```

It's still not clear why you need a lambda, but if you do, you can simply wrap it in a `Func` (as per my above answer) or in a `Predicate` (as per Mrinal Kamboj's answer).

Comment: Why not `Func<string,bool>`, wouldn't that be a better choice

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Because I'm making the assumption that OP passing the same string twice was a product of the simplification he did for the purpose of the question, and because I think using closure in this case makes the code cleaner. (That one's a personal preference.)